# Visual Studio / Expression - RemoteException

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2012, geolocation, expression-blend

When creating a WP7 project with geolocation, the VS2012 UI designer throws this error:

```
Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteException
Could not load file or assembly 'LocationService.Interop, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24eec0d8c86cda1e' or one of its dependencies. System could not find the specified file.
   in System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   in System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher.Finalize()
```

I searched throughout Google and StackOverflow and found nothing useful. If I reload the designer it works for one minute or two in Visual Studio 2012. However, Expression Blend crashes immediately if I try to open the project.

This is the content of one of my pages (but it crashes in every page regardless of the contents):

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="Dropi.MapView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps" Loaded="onLoaded" Unloaded="onViewUnloaded">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28"></StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <my:Map Height="717" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="myMap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450" CredentialsProvider="ApxwcCwErohOLVMieO3OPc0MrdT379URDUphvhbyR10udU9QmiYBK2urEPZZ1pl-" Mode="Road" ZoomBarVisibility="Visible" ZoomLevel="12"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>

<!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
<!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you have on your page? Can you possible post some xaml & code to help locate the issue?

Comment: Sure, I edited my post with the contents of a page (basically just a map occupying the whole page).

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with your code in the VS designer or the designer in Expression Blend. It loads just fine. 
Can you confirm the following;

That you have the latest visual studio update installed(http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36833)
That you are referencing the correct DLL, for the right version of of Windows Phone. My DLL info is as follows: 

Name: Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps

Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Libraries\Silverlight\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.dll
Runtime version: v2.0.50727

Version: 7.0.0.0

Comment: Hmm, I'm referencing this DLL: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Libraries\Silverlight\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.dll

Runtime: v.2.0.50727
Version 7.0.0.0

Seems to be exactly the same as yours... I will check VS updates! Do you think that it could be something in the C# code-behind?

Comment: Nope, same problem, even after update...

Comment: Are you running on a virtual machine or have installed any beta version of VS on the machine you are running the code? 
Also, does the emulator work? - Also what version of Visual studio are you running on which OS?

Comment: I'm running Visual Studio Professional 2012, version 11.0.060223.01 Update 2 CTP with .NET Framework Version 4.5.50709. It is running on a laptop (Asus N56V) with Windows 8 Professional. The emulator is running ok, only the VS (UI designer actually) is crashing... :/

Comment: Ok' the same as me except VS Ultimate. 
If you are sure you are referencing the right dll' it must me broken else where.
Try repairing or reinstalling the Windows Phone SDK - if that doens't help, you might have to go as far as repairing or reinstalling Visual Studio.

Comment: I have just reinstalled Windows SDK and repaired Visual Studio... Still, it didn't work... :(

Comment: Can you share your solution at skydrive or dropbox?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. To solve it, I just did something like this:

```
 if (!ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
 {
     _watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High) { MovementThreshold = 5 };
 }
```

[update]
This is the MVVM Light solution. You can check if you're in design mode by checking System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Hmm, I can't seem to find ViewModelBase, where does that come from? :/